# Online wiki / documentation for project schema / requirements?

Tags: wiki, requirements

I have my development team who are across the world. Outsourced to different companies and I need to have a central Wiki where we can all store, edit, view notes on the project. Any suggestions for this? Only requirement is it should be free and if possible have some tools so i can show images / document database schema?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [wikimatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/). There are all kinds of wiki systems listed. I personally like [dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) and of course the biggest system [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki).

There are tons of recommendations on [webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/131/for-a-software-development-project-what-is-the-best-type-of-wiki)